# Отправляет не те значения(ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Вывод список категорий:

```
<?php foreach($category as $cat) :?>

   <li><a class="cat" href="#" data-id="<?=$cat['cat_id']?>"><?=$cat['name']?></a></li>

<?php endforeach?>
```

Jquery:

```
 $(function(){
    var base_url = '<?php base_url();?>';
    $('.cat').click(function(){

        data={id: $('.cat').data('id')};
        console.log(data);
        $.post(base_url+'getContentByCategory', data, function(){

        });
    });
```

На какую ссылку бы я не нажал, отправляет id = 1 всегда, хотя если посмотреть в браузере, то id разные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Странно, что вообще отправляет единицу, ибо вы выбираете коллекцию объектов с классом `cat` у которого даже нет такого атрибута, как `data-id`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, у первого на странице возможно есть :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяй

`data = {id: $('.cat').data('id')};`

на

`data = {id: $('a', this).data('id')};`

Ты не то берешь и не оттуда берешь. В этом и проблема.

В твоем случае ты берешь из всех найденных (либо первого) атрибута `data-id`, но у `.cat` нет этого атрибута. Чтобы взять этот параметр тебе нужно обратиться к твоему тегу `a` в области `this`, где `this` - область где сработал `.click` у `.cat`

Comment: Я понял! Спасибо )

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сменить контекст обращения на this.

```
data = {
    id: $(this).data('id')
};
```